# Trying to add rounded borders around text in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am working for a small startup, and I was tasked with implementing a settings screen design. Based off of what they designed, they want like a box that fits the screen with text on top of it that serves as a breaker between each section of the settings. I just can't figure out how to round the corners around the text.

So far what I did was:

```
<View className="w-full mt-2">
   <Text style={styles.TextComponentStyle}>Account</Text>
</View>
```

And the style sheet looks like this:

```
TextComponentStyle: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderColor: '#DADEE8',
    borderWidth: .5,
    color: 'black',
    backgroundColor: '#DADEE8',
    padding: 2,
    fontSize: 16,
    margin: 10
  }
```

It is giving me almost everything I want minus the rounded corners. It is showing up as square corners.

Answer (score 0):

The `Text` element in React Native doesn't take border properties. You should apply the border properties to the container around the text element.

This should work for you:

```
<View className="w-full mt-2" style={styles.textContainer}>
   <Text style={styles.TextComponentStyle}>Account</Text>
</View>
```

```
TextContainer: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderColor: '#DADEE8',
    borderWidth: .5,
    backgroundColor: '#DADEE8',
    padding: 2,
    margin: 10,

},

TextComponentStyle: {
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 16,
}
```